# vb.net XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode and xmlNamespace issue

Tags: vb.net, xml-namespaces, selectsinglenode

I am trying to get this code working but somehow is not getting the content

My Code

```
Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
    Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
    Dim m_node As XmlNode
    'Create the XML Document
    m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
    'Load the Xml file
    m_xmld.Load("http://feeds.thescore.com/nfl.rss")
    'Get the list of name nodes 
    m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item")

    Dim content As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
    content.AddNamespace("content", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")

    'Loop through the nodes
    For Each m_node In m_nodelist
        If Not m_node.SelectSingleNode("content:encoded",content) Is Nothing AndAlso Len(m_node.SelectSingleNode("content:encoded",content).InnerText) > 0 Then 
            response.Write(m_node.SelectSingleNode("content:encoded",content))
            response.Flush()
        end if

    Next
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: My answer shows how to get all of the content:encoded values.  Didn't know what response was.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way and could see all of the content nodes, that appear to be html.

```
Imports <xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
Imports <xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
Imports <xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
Imports <xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">
Imports <xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim xe As XElement = XElement.Load("http://feeds.thescore.com/nfl.rss")

        Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xe...<content:encoded>

        For Each c As XElement In ie
            Debug.WriteLine(c.Value)
        Next
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: how to do for asp.net version of it as imports and i only can import as namespace <%@ Import "<xmlns:atom=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"">" %>

Answer (score 0):

I managed with different approach I import first the data with webClient replaced the  with  and worked like a charm